# "As pets being welcome, she stayed at the hotel with her dog."

Tags: grammaticality, participles, participial-phrases

I know that the the following two sentences are validly structured.

> Pets being welcome, she stayed at the hotel with her dog.

and

> As pets were welcome, she stayed at the hotel with her dog.

The following sentence combines elements of the first two sentences.  Is this third sentence grammatically valid, and if not, why not?

> **As pets being welcome, she stayed at the hotel with her dog.**

Answer (score 13):

In the sentence about which you are asking, the word *being* is a present participle, and is used in a manner that is awkward. The [subordinating conjunction](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/subordinating-conjunctions/) *as* normally would introduce a [dependent clause](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/dependent_clause.htm).  That dependent clause would need to have a verb.  Since *being* is not acting as a verb, that group of words does not form a proper clause, and so it sounds awkward.

Omitting *as*, as you do in the first sentence, works well, and might even be the best choice.  I would classify *Pets being welcome* as an [absolute phrase](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/grammar/sentences/what-is-an-absolute-phrase.html) that modifies the independent clause.

The second sentence is proper.  It is proper because *were* acts as a verb. A proper dependent clause thus is formed, and so *As* properly acts a subordinating conjunction introducing that clause.  Also, I note that the verb tenses match:  *were* and *stayed*.

Comment: "As pets being welcome" is not grammatically correct, but if you *say* it most native English speakers would know what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recommendation based on common style (such as AP) and standard usage:

*Because pets were welcomed, she stayed at the hotel with her dog.*

Here are reasons for this recommendation:

"Because" is a less stylized, more understandable word for describing a cause than "as".

"Were welcomed" is a more simple form than "Being welcome", especially for a circumstance that was completely in the past.